# NavigationTitle delay on iOS 16.1 when using NavigationSplitView

Tags: swiftui, ios16, swiftui-navigationsplitview, navigationsplitview

Is anyone else facing this issue with iOS 16.1 `NavigationSplitView` where the `NavigationTitle` loads after the view is loaded? – works fine on iOS 16.0. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0IUG.gif)

It's literally the same code, but it's giving me issues specifically only on iOS 16.1.

Update: This is still an issue on iOS 16.2 and 16.3.

Update by [@Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74481116/navigationtitle-delay-on-ios-16-1-when-using-navigationsplitview#comment133169871_74481116): Apple has seemingly fixed this issue on iOS 16.4 Beta 1.

Comment: Yes, seeing the same. Filed as FB11713004 if you want to dupe it.

Comment: Unfortunately still seems to be a thing with 16.3. My feedback report does say others have reported it but not many. Dupe it if you can, get more traffic on this weird issue.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 16.4b1 - seeing things animate / appear correctly now.

Comment: @Hunter thanks a ton for all the updates here! Really glad to hear that Apple seem to have finally fixed it... 

Comment: I'm seeing this on 16.2 simulators, going to update to 16.4 and report later.